# USB auto passthrough to KVM

Tags: ubuntu, usb, linux-kvm, automount

I feel like there should be an answer for this but everything I have tried seems to land me in the same boat. I am trying to use a single USB port on my computer that gets a USB -> microSD card reader plugged in and out multiple times a day while testing android ROM's. This single USB port should always and forever mount anything plugged into it to the guest OS. Doesnt matter to me if its a mouse or a flash drive or a rocket launcher... mount anything in that port to the guest.

My host is Ubuntu 16.04 with a Win8.1 guest

What happens: I plug in the usb -> microSD reader and go to virt manager where i add a new hardware device for the USB device. I format and burn a ROM image to that SD card and eject from win8.1 guest (bottom tray not in virt manager). I unplug the adapter and use the SD card as intended. I plug the device back into the computer with the SD card and nothing happens. I go to virt manager and it shows the hardware device but no details. I have to remove the hardware device of which (as expected) the host picks it up and mounts it. I re-add the hardware device and "sometimes" the guest will mount it other times the host re-mounts it. seems haphazard as to when it will and wont mount but certainly does not auto mount as expected.